# has Yplot ever been a Python module?

Tags: python

I just got a script from work and a module called Yplot appears, my colleage mentioned that it uses a previous python version 3.7, 3.4 or maybe another one. I need help knowing how to import this module, if this module actually exists or how to replace it. I'll leave a couple of codelines that use it.

`import matplotlib as mpl`
`import yplot as yp`
`yp.yParams.time_locator = mpl.dates.MonthLocator([3, 6, 9, 12])`
`yp.yParams.annot_series = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

I tried importing with pip, conda and googling it, no luck.

Comment: What does your colleague say about what yplot is and where to get it from?